# Passing value of script variable to the playbook output

Tags: ansible

I'm quite new to Ansible so I'm still in learning curve. I'm looking for a way to retrieve a value from script's variable and use it further along with ansible-playbook command.

Saying I have a script I would like to retrieve `$hostname` info in target node. The script is run in a playbook. When a `$HOSTNAME` value returns, how can I pass it to my wrapper script so I can reference it with other list?

The script is as simple as follows:

```
HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
ECHO "$HOSTNAME"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running a script with ansible in one task, you would register the output:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Echo value
      command: "echo Hello"
      register: command_output
```

Then in your next task, maybe you want to create a file for the hostname:

```
  - shell: "touch {{ item }} "
    with_items:
      - "{{ command_output.stdout_lines }}"
```

That's the basic structure - you don't say what command you want to run, but this should get you started.
Here's a nice tutorial: http://www.mydailytutorials.com/ansible-register-variables/